# Where to ask questions related to restorations?

Tags: discussion, support, questions, site-recommendation

On which site in the Stack Exchange network should I ask my questions related to *restoration* of old stuff??

PS: I don’t know if this is inappropriate to ask this question here, but I thought it would be better rather than creating a nuisance on some unrelated site.

Comment: what sort of old stuff?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek stuffs like old wooden/metal etc. which need some kind of restorations, you see :)

Comment: @user377340 You could have that added to your question in first place to clarify. But I believe I found the correct site you're looking for, so no harm done. The non (engineering) technical sites are a bit harder to find from the site overview.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  How do you find the correct site you want for your questions??

Comment: @user377340 You can find an overview of all sites if you click the [**MORE STACK EXCHANGE COMMUNITIES**](https://stackexchange.com/sites) link that appears with the nav-bar burger menu looking icon at the rightmost side. If you feel your question could fit there, you can always make yourself sure and take their [tour] and visit the [help/on-topic].

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Great!

Comment: I was going to say that using the network wide search might also give an initial hint which site might be appropriate but for [restoration](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=restoration) that didn't work out well ...

Comment: @rene It worked to find it at the site specific search

Answer (score 2):

I believe you could ask your questions about a restoration project at the

[**Arts & Crafts beta**](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/)

site.
A quick look at their [on-topic](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) section in the help center says:

> - Tool usage, upkeep and selection
> - Material selection and usage
> - Asking for clarification of a specific tutorial step ("why isn't this working?" or "what do these instructions mean?")
> - Attributes of different media and how they interact
> - Proper media storage and final product preservation

Chances are high you may find good and helpful answers there, fitting with your restoration project already.

---

They even provide an established [<kbd>restoration</kbd>](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/restoration) tag with the following info text:

> For questions concerning methods to restore damaged or time-worn works and materials.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation :) I was wondering if they entertain opinion based (not too broad) questions over there??

Comment: @user377340 Well, they discourage [**subjective**](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) questions.